# Create a Heroku add-on using Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-addon

I want to create a Heroku Add-on using Nodejs but cannot find any resource. I have gone through the documentation available on Heroku but it is showing examples of ruby. **I wanted to know if it is actually possible to create using node?** Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Addons communite with Heroku via HTTP, so you just to send HTTP request to Heroku with Node.js

Ref: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-partner-api-reference